# Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr, : 'dimnames' length [2] must be the same as the displayed area

Tags: r, csv, matrix

I want to use cprrplot for visualization, but there is an error

> dataset1 <- read.csv("winequality-white.csv",header=T)
>   View(dataset1)
>   head(dataset1)
>     fixed.acidity volatile.acidity citric.acid residual.sugar chlorides free.sulfur.dioxide total.sulfur.dioxide density   pH sulphates alcohol
>   1           7.0             0.27        0.36           20.7     0.045                  45                  170  1.0010 3.00      0.45     8.8
>   2           6.3             0.30        0.34            1.6     0.049                  14                  132  0.9940 3.30      0.49     9.5
>   3           8.1             0.28        0.40            6.9     0.050                  30                   97  0.9951 3.26      0.44    10.1
>   4           7.2             0.23        0.32            8.5     0.058                  47                  186  0.9956 3.19      0.40     9.9
>   5           7.2             0.23        0.32            8.5     0.058                  47                  186  0.9956 3.19      0.40     9.9
>   6           8.1             0.28        0.40            6.9     0.050                  30                   97  0.9951 3.26      0.44    10.1
>   dataset1 <- read.csv("winequality-white.csv",header=T)
>   View(dataset1)
>   M<-cor(dataset1)
>   library(corrplot)
>
> ## correlogram with hclust reordering
>
> corrplot(dataset1, type ="upper", order="hclust")
>   Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : 
>     'dimnames'的长度[2]必需与陈列范围相等
>   corrplot(as.matrix(dataset1), type="upper", order="hclust")
>   Error in corrplot(as.matrix(dataset1), type = "upper", order = "hclust") : 
>     The matrix is not in [-1, 1]!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXR1I.png)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to debug this ERROR is as follows:

```
library("corrplot")
dataset1 <- read.csv("winequality-white.csv",header=T) 
# Below is the keypoint!
cor_dataset1 <- cor(datset1)  
corrplot(cor_dataset1, type ="upper", order="hclust")
```